# Curly Braces with {} grep and regular expressions: Why does it exceed the maximum value?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep, curly-braces

I've been self-studying shell scripting for a while now, and I came across this section of a Linux Fundamentals manual concerning grep and curly braces {}. My problem is that when I'm demanding a string pattern to search for using grep from a minimum to a maximum number of occurrences using {} or curly braces, my result exceeds the maximum that I specified.

Here is what happened:

```
Express11:~/unix_training/reg_ex # cat reg_file2
ll
lol
lool
loool
loooose
Express11:~/unix_training/reg_ex # grep -E 'o{2,3}' reg_file2
lool
loool
loooose
Express11:~/unix_training/reg_ex #
```

When according to the manual, should not be the case as I am specifying here that I am only looking for strings containing two consecutive o's to three consecutive o's.

EDIT: Actually, the reason why I did not understand how the curly braces worked was because of this simplistic explanation by the manual. And I quote:

> 19.4.10. between n and m times
>   And here we demand exactly from minimum 2 to maximum 3 times.
>
> ```
> paul@debian7:~$ cat list2
> ll
> lol
> lool
> loool
> paul@debian7:~$ grep -E 'o{2,3}' list2
> lool
> loool
> paul@debian7:~$ grep 'o\{2,3\}' list2
> lool
> loool
> paul@debian7:~$ cat list2 | sed 's/o\{2,3\}/A/'
> ll
> lol
> lAl
> lAl
> paul@debian7:~$
> ```

Thanks to all those who replied.

Comment: The great thing about Google is that it lets you take a description like "this simplistic explanation by the manual" and find out what "manual" is being referred to. It's actually not a manual at all; it's a book called "Linux Fundamentals" by Paul Cobbaut, an introdutory text for novice administrators, which is not specifically about regular expressions at all. There is a regex manpage (probably on your system: try `man 7 regex`) and there are lots of regex resources around the web. Some of them are even not too bad.

Comment: In this special case, you could understand that you want 2, but not 4 consecutive `o`s. So you could use: `grep oo reg_file2 | grep -v oooo`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
# grep -E 'o{2,3}' reg_file2
lool
loool
loooose
```

Command works perfectly, that it matches the first three o's in the last line. That's why you get also last line in the final output.

I think the command you're actually looking for is,

```
$ grep -P '(?<!o)o{2,3}(?!o)' file
lool
loool
```

**Explanation:**

- `(?<!o)` negative lookbehind which asserts that the match won't be preceded by the letter `o`.
- `o{2,3}` Matches 2 or 3 o's.
- `(?!o)` Negative lookahead which asserts that the match won't be followed by the letter `o`.

**OR**

```
$ grep -E '(^|[^o])o{2,3}($|[^o])' file
lool
loool
```

**Explanation:**

- `(^|[^o])` Matches the start of a line `^` or any character but not of `o`
- `o{2,3}` Matches 2 or 3 o's
- `($|[^o])` Matches the end of the line `$` or any character but not of `o`

Comment: Thank you for the humble response.

Answer (score 2):

You are not clear with how regex works.

The pattern `o{2,3}` in grep will go through each line looking for `oo` and `ooo`, As long as there is a match, Grep will get you that line. Since you didn't add other rules in your pattern, What you get from `grep -E 'o{2,3}' reg_file2` is correct.

I guess in your case you only want a two or three consecutive letter 'o's, Thus you will need to use regex like what Raj answesed. Matching `oo` or `ooo` which is neither following nor followed by the letter 'o'.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I edited my question and I only started using regular expressions for only a week based on a basic manual.